# Ubuntu NFS Server

Tags: nfs

I a completely new to Linux but I have ubuntu server running on a virtual machine (oracle Virtual box) and NFS installed. Do the files need to reside on this virtual machine? I have Windows 7 pc that has all my files and wondering if I can map a drive or share? I was planning to leave the virtual running all the time to host the files. Am I completely off with the purpose of a NFS server?

Any advice or info would be great.